# Why is blur.js trying to access the file "none"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transparency

I'm trying to use blur.js to create a blur effect on my site so you can see the site background behind the content. However, it appears to be trying to access an image called "none."

Here is the output from the chrome javascript log:

```
$('#container').blurjs({source: 'body',radius: 10});
[
<div id=​"container">​…
]
GET http://rymate.x10.mx/test/none 404 (Not Found) blur.min.js:285
(anonymous function) blur.min.js:285
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.7.1.js:271
$.fn.blurjs blur.min.js:199
(anonymous function)
InjectedScript._evaluateOn
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap
InjectedScript.evaluate
```

My code is online at https://gist.github.com/rymate1234/6162990 and also on http://rymate.x10.mx/test/.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: insert the line `console.log($source.css('backgroundImage'));` around line 200.  I suspect that's your problem.

Comment: @archer the output in the log is precisely "none"

Comment: That's what it's trying to add as an image source on line 285.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in the plugin, it assumes that the element you pass to the plugin has a valid URL as a source.

That could be a reasonable assumption but it doesn't handle the situation where there is no background image in the source element, that's when the browser reports `"none"`.

You should probably report it if you care about the plugin because it is undesired and useless load on the server.

Anyway, you should also use the plugin correctly, what you want is:

```
source: '#page'
```

However, the source image must be hosted by you, not `onlinedesign4uu.co.uk` because cross-origin image will not work.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It works now, and I've alerted the dev of the bug.