# Blur.Js without backgroundimage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a navigation which has a alpha and blurs out whatever is behind.
I use Blur.Js and had an error wich i fixed with the help of this side:

[Why is blur.js trying to access the file "none"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076401/why-is-blur-js-trying-to-access-the-file-none/24112697#24112697)

Now i get 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined   blur.min.js:6

i guess the function which causes it is:

```
return this.each(function(){var A=l(this),I=l(e.source),B=I.css("backgroundImage").replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig,"");
```

is there a possibilty how to fix this so i can use it without a background image?

Comment: you're using the minified version of the library; it's hard to figure out what exactly is going wrong.  Could you try using the development (un-compressed, un-minified) version to see if you can potentially get a better error message?

Comment: btw. not even the demo is running. It says:  Uncaught Error: unable to access image data: Error: unable to access local image data: ReferenceError: netscape is not defined. Maybe that helps

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined   /C:/Users/Oliver/Desktop/Portfolio_megafolder/Portfolio4/blur.js:196  
  
I used the normal blur.js now.   

var formattedSource = ($source.css('backgroundImage')).replace(/"/g, "").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");  

this is the refered code line.  
thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sadly, I think blur.js requires a background image.